# Vector add (new(type)) it's null

Tags: java, android

I'm working with a JSONObject (with Android), and I need to read this object, and to save in a Vector, to define in the same method but this Vector is a type class contac (this contain his contructors and get and set). When a going to save, Vector.add create null, and it doesn't return anything.

This the code:

```
    Vector <contac> Contactos;
    Contactos = new Vector<contac>();

    JSONArray objeto=obj.getJSONArray("results");

    if (objeto !=null){

        for (int i=0;i<objeto.length();i++){
             JSONObject objeto1=objeto.getJSONObject(i);
             Contactos.add(new contac(objeto1.optString("number"),objeto1.optString("sexo"),objeto1.optString("nombre"),objeto1.optString("apellido"),objeto1.optString("calle"),objeto1.optString("ciudad"),objeto1.optString("provincia"),objeto1.optString("pais"),objeto1.optString("postal"),objeto1.optString("email"),objeto1.optString("telephonenumber"),objeto1.optString("birthday"),objeto1.optString("kilogram"),objeto1.optString("centimetres"),objeto1.optString("guid"),objeto1.optString("latitude"),objeto1.optString("longitude"),objeto1.optString("image")));

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share your json data..!

Answer (score 0):

It don't even know if it could solve your problem, but be sure to correctly name your variables :

**First character of variables name are lower case, Class starts with an upper case.**

You should write :

```
Vector contactos; = new Vector();
JSONArray objeto = obj.getJSONArray("results");
     if (objeto != null){
            for (int i=0;i<objeto.length();i++){
                  JSONObject objeto1=objeto.getJSONObject(i);
                  contactos.add(new Contac(objeto1.optString("number"),objeto1.optString("sexo"),objeto1.optString("nombre"),objeto1.optString("apellido"),objeto1.optString("calle"),objeto1.optString("ciudad"),objeto1.optString("provincia"),objeto1.optString("pais"),objeto1.optString("postal"),objeto1.optString("email"),objeto1.optString("telephonenumber"),objeto1.optString("birthday"),objeto1.optString("kilogram"),objeto1.optString("centimetres"),objeto1.optString("guid"),objeto1.optString("latitude"),objeto1.optString("longitude"),objeto1.optString("image")));
            }
     }
```